# How can I use C-dependent Perl modules on an M1 Mac?

Tags: macos, perl

I'm moving to a new M1 Mac and am having a lot of trouble with certain Perl modules. They seem to be the ones that aren't pure Perl but are dependent on C libraries to run.

For instance, I installed `Text::CSV` to work on some CSV files. It seems to be installed correctly, as does `Text::CSV_XS`. But when I run a script that uses `Text::CSV` I get the following:

```
Can't load '/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Text/CSV_XS/CSV_XS.bundle' for module Text::CSV_XS: dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Text/CSV_XS/CSV_XS.bundle, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Text/CSV_XS/CSV_XS.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Text/CSV_XS/CSV_XS.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture at /System/Library/Perl/5.30/XSLoader.pm line 96.
 at /Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Text/CSV_XS.pm line 32.
Compilation failed in require at /Library/Perl/5.30/Parse/CSV.pm line 114.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Library/Perl/5.30/Parse/CSV.pm line 114.
Compilation failed in require at ia.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ia.pl line 3.
```

Not sure if it matters, but I installed the module using `cpanm` in a terminal window that was running under the `open using Rosetta` option.

`Text::CSV` is just one example. I'm having similar issues with `XML::LibXML`, `MARC::Record`, and `MARC::File::XML`.

Any suggestions on how to get these modules working on my M1 Mac would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Installation fails due missing header files and libraries, CPU binary incompatibility with existing files. You need to find a way to provide these files. In worst case you have to compile missing files/libraries from source. Check your OS if there is a package management utility which can provide required missing files/libraries.

Comment: Did the libraries install correctly, including running all tests successfully? Are you running your script via Rosetta as well?

Comment: In the case of Text::CSV, I was able to get it to work if I install the module under Rosetta, but run the script outside Rosetta. But that trick doesn't work for some other modules.

Comment: Are you using macOS Big Sur? Are you using the system perl? I would recommend using perlbrew, since there has been reported several issues (like [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682584)) with installing modules (especially XS modules depending on external libraries) using the system perl on macOS Big Sur

Comment: @anaximander I tried to install Text::CSV with perlbrew perl version 5.34.0 on my macBook Air Apple M1 laptop with BigSur 11.4. It installed fine; [here](https://pastebin.com/9bnG8kNZ) is the install log for reference

Comment: Thanks so much, @HåkonHægland! I'm installing perlbrew now! I'll post again soon.

Comment: Saved by perlbrew! I installed it and I'm able to install modules (both pure Perl and XS) and run scripts. Thank you, @HåkonHægland!